# Sidebar when collapse show submenu

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I followed the tutorial from https://bootstrapious.com/p/bootstrap-sidebar **#4 Advanced sidebar** to get the sidebar function working. The problem I am currently facing is during collapse and hover, the submenu is not showing nicely as showed below

[sidebar1 when collapse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLh0x.png)

[sidebar2 when collapse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgdxL.png)

Can anyone help me? I'm really new with css. I want the submenu to be align with their parent and i want to display the header together with the list inside submenu like this image

[Example how i want my hover to show when collapse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiAaV.png)

Before we start, I have a few questions:-

1. Why the submenu display slightly lower from their parent?
2. Is there any tips or a way for me to play/improve my css understanding?

This is my **css**

```
/*    wrapper stretch value will equalize both page content and sidebar height.
As the content increases, sidebar height dynamically increases.*/
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
}

#sidebar {
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
}

/* Shrinking the sidebar from 250px to 80px and center aligining its content*/
#sidebar.active {
    min-width: 80px;
    max-width: 80px;
    text-align: center;
}

.components:hover {
    display: block;
}
/*------------On hover will show submenu when collapse---------------*/
#sidebar.active > .components > li:hover .collapse {
    background-color: #1E88E5;
    display: block;
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 20px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99999;
    left: 222px;
}
/*------------End On hover willshow submenu when collapse---------------*/

a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 20px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

body {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    background: #fafafa;
}

p {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.7em;
    color: #999;
}

a, a:hover, a:focus {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

#sidebar {
    color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

    #sidebar .sidebar-header {
        padding: 20px;
        background: #1E88E5;  /*This is template color*/
        border-bottom-color: coral;
    }

    #sidebar ul.components {
        padding: 20px 0;
   }

    #sidebar ul p {
        color: #fff;
        padding: 10px;
    }

    #sidebar ul li a {
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 1.1em;
        display: block;
    }

    #sidebar ul li a:hover {
        color: #FFB22B;
    }


ul ul a sidebar {
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    padding-left: 30px !important;
    background: #6d7fcc;
}
```

**Jquery**

```
$('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function () {
        $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
    });

    // Collapse click
    $('[data-toggle=sidebar-colapse]').click(function () {
        SidebarCollapse();
    });

    function SidebarCollapse() {
        $('.menu-collapsed').toggleClass('d-none');
        $('#dropdown-toggle').toggleClass('d-none');
        $('#collapse-icon').toggleClass('fa-angle-double-left fa-angle-double-right');
    }
```

**HTML** these two codes below, 1st for the button while 2nd code is the sidebar and lores ipsum

```
<div class="row page-titles">
<div class="col-md-12 col-12 align-self-center">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="row col-8 mt-3">
            <div class="col-1">
                <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="sidebar-colapse">
                    <i class="fas fa-align-left"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-start" id="main">
<div class="wrapper nav">
    <!-- Sidebar  -->
    <nav id="sidebar">
        <ul class="list-unstyled components">
            <li>
                <a id="SalesPer" href="#SalesPerformanceSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">
                    <i class="fas fa-chart-area"></i>
                    <span class="menu-collapsed">Chart</span>
                </a>
                <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="SalesPerformanceSubmenu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Chart1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Chart2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Chart3</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#contactsSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">
                    <i class="fas fa-address-card"></i>
                    <span class="menu-collapsed">People</span>
                </a>
                <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="contactsSubmenu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">People1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">People2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">People3</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#documentSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">
                    <i class="fas fa-laptop"></i>
                    <span class="menu-collapsed">Activities</span>
                </a>
                <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="documentSubmenu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Activities1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Activities2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Activities3</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
<div class="row" id="MainCardDiv">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you upload a working demo by combining all these code - html , css and js ?